# Gradle Stuck and taking long time after updating Android studio 3.0 stable update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have updated Android studio to 3.0 stable release version. My project and its corresponding dependencies are working fine upto 2.3.3 Android version.

But since yesterday, Gradle build is taking so long and got stuck at processes while resolving dependencies. Please check below screenshot of build.gradle file:

[image]

I have checked gradle setting too, trying using Gradle wrapper or Local Gradle Distribution method, but no luck. Please see below setting :

[image]

And, my gradle-wrapper.properties file look like :

```
#Thu Oct 26 17:52:06 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

I tried Gradle clean / assemble / Sync project and every other approach before posting this question, but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run gradle from the terminal instead of the IDE to find any difference?

Comment: check this link it may help you https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: @cricket_007 , yes i tried running gradlew clean build --stacktrace command. It failed there too.

Comment: You need `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'` if you are using Gradle 4.1

Comment: Try `File->Invalid Caches/Restart`, invalid the caches and restart. Then run build again.

Comment: @cricket_007 , just updated after posting this question and looking into Kuldip response. And updated compile to implementation further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I resolve this issue, after upgrading to Android studio 3.0 :

1. Changed old build version to at least: buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
2. Changed compile to implementation
3. Changed testCompile to androidTestImplementation
4. Changed older classpath version to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
5. If using local gradle distribution then verify distributionUrl as 4.1-all.zip
6. Deleted .gradle folder then Clean / Rebuild.

It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Which gradle folder did you delete?

Comment: @TrentPierce , I deleted .gradle folder inside project directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you upgraded android studio to a newer version, the version of gradle will also be updated.

The message "Refreshing project" means a new version of gradle is being downloaded. About 100MB of file will be downloaded in the meantime.

So make sure you have a stable internet connection and wait for some time till the download completes.

Another possibility:

You have used `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` in your build.gradle file. Use the [corresponding version of gradle as the version of Android Gradle Build Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html). So use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` with Gradle 4.1+

Comment: What about "Using local gradle", as shown in the question? Its already downloaded then

Comment: The gradle Android build plugin version is independent of the Gradle version, by the way

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem yesterday. After upgrading from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0, it took a long time to build the project. First, you need to waiting for the Android Studio to download the gradle if you don't use the local gradle. Second, you need to clear by `File->Invalid Caches/Restart`. Last, you need to delete the `.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependencies like:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this error happens when it is blocked in your country,then you need to use a VPN like hotspotshield 
this worked for me